# sink() doesn't work in tryCatch block

Tags: r, logging, exception, try-catch, sink

I'm trying to close my logger instance in a finally block, as follows:

```
logger <- file("all.Rout", open="wt")           
sink(logger, type="message")                                 

tryCatch({
    warning('test')
    message("A")
    log('a')
    message("B")
}, error = function(e) {
}, finally = {
    sink(type="message")
    close(logger)
})
```

However, only `message("A")` is saved to log and nothing else is. If I do the follow, the problem is fixed:

```
logger <- file("all.Rout", open="wt")           
sink(logger, type="message")                                 

tryCatch({
    warning('test')
    message("A")
    log('a')
    message("B")
}, error = function(e) {
}, finally = {
})

sink(type="message")
close(logger)
```

However, I really need the closing to be in the `finally` block so that I can view the logs if an error was thrown.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the default setting is not to print `warnings` as they happen. They are accumulated and then printed when convenient. So R doesn't think the `finally` block is a convenient time to print those warnings because you aren't ineractive at that point and might not see them. One work-around is to change the setting to report every warning as it happens rather than waiting till the current call is done. you can do that with this

```
logger <- file("log.txt", open="wt")           
sink(logger, type="message")                                 

tryCatch({
    ow<-options(warn=1)
    warning('test')
    message("A")
    log('a')
    message("B")
}, 
error = function(e) {
}, finally = {
    options(ow)
    sink(type="message")
    close(logger)
})
```

Here we change the `options()` at the beginning of the try block and then reset them in the finally.

The contents of the log file are then

```
Warning in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : test
A
```

You'll notice in the other method the messages are reversed even though the warning come first. Again, R was just waiting till the end of the current call to return the warnings messages to you and that was after the `tryCatch()` finished running.

Comment: An alternative is to overwrite the option warning.expression ala: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433848/handling-errors-before-warnings-in-trycatch/19446931#19446931