# Catching Output of a Library Function

Tags: r

I'm really at a loss here. I found a couple of threads here on stack overflow on how to redirect the output of a function, but none of it seems to be working in my case.

I'm using arima from the `library(forecast)` for a lot of (generated) timeseries, and some of them have bad properties, which results in `auto.arima()` printing out an error and a warning. I'm unable to catch this Error in anyway, be it via `tryCatch` or `capture.output()` (which only captures the normal forecast).

The goal is to capture the error message (and warning) thrown by the example below and react to it. So basically at the end i would have the error and the forecast (despite being errorneous) in some variable form.

I appreciate any suggestions, the following is the minimal example to produce the error:

```
library(forecast)
testt <- c(826,816,839,995,697)
testend <- c(2015,164)
testseries <- ts(testt,end=testend,frequency=365)
auto.arima(testseries)
#tryCatch not working:
testfc <- tryCatch(forecast(auto.arima(testseries),h=1), error=function(e) NA)
#capture.output not working:
result <- capture.output(auto.arima(testseries))
```

Comment: What ... exactly ... are you trying to capture? I get: `Error in arima(x, order = c(1, d, 0), xreg = xreg) :    non-stationary AR part from CSS`

Comment: @42-  OP is trying to capture the error thrown by `auto.arima`. The example is deliberately not working, in order to throw an error.

Comment: I think the goals of the OP remain ambiguous. The output (to the console) from that call to `auto.arima` includes both an error message and a model summary. Since the error report doesn't actually halt execution, the call does return an object with class `c("ARIMA","arima")`. So the goals of the coding need to be clarified. There are two different answers that have interpreted these goals divergently.

Comment: @42- Pascal was actually right, i'm still unsure what other case you mean. edit: got it now, will edit my main post. Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can capture the errors and warnings with the `type="message"` argument to `capture.output`. `type` can be either "output", which captures the function output, or "message", which captures the errors and warnings. The function below uses `sapply` to allow you to run `capture.output` once with each argument, storing the results in a list.

```
capture.errors = function(type, data) {
  sapply(type, function(type) {
    capture.output(auto.arima(data), type=type)
  }, simplify=FALSE)
}

out = capture.errors(c("output","message"), testseries)

out

$output
[1] "Series: data "                                    
[2] "ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean "                 
[3] ""                                                 
[4] "Coefficients:"                                    
[5] "      intercept"                                  
[6] "       834.6000"                                  
[7] "s.e.    42.4746"                                  
[8] ""                                                 
[9] "sigma^2 estimated as 9020:  log likelihood=-29.86"
[10] "AIC=63.73   AICc=69.73   BIC=62.94"               

$message
[1] "Error in arima(x, order = c(1, d, 0), xreg = xreg) : "
[2] "  non-stationary AR part from CSS"                    
[3] "In addition: Warning message:"                        
[4] "In auto.arima(data) : Unable to calculate AIC offset"
```

Since capturing the model output with `capture.output` probably isn't as useful as capturing the "real" output in the model object, maybe the function below would be better. It returns a list with the model object and any error or warning messages:

```
capture = function(data) {
list(model=auto.arima(data),
     message=capture.output(auto.arima(data), type="message"))
}
```

The model object is available in the usual way, so below I just look at the message output.

```
out1 = capture(testseries)

# Show any errors and warnings
out1[["message"]]
[1] "Error in arima(x, order = c(1, d, 0), xreg = xreg) : "
[2] "  non-stationary AR part from CSS"                    
[3] "In addition: Warning message:"                        
[4] "In auto.arima(data) : Unable to calculate AIC offset" 

out2 = capture(cumsum(rnorm(100)))

# No errors or warnings with this data set
out2[["message"]]
character(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, the capture function with the list was exactly what i was looking for! :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to suppress printing of the error message. (That at least appears to be the goal of your call to `tryCatch()`.) One way to do that is to, immediately before your call to `auto.arima()`, divert any error messages to a temporary file, using `sink(..., type="message")`. Then, right after the call, clean up by stopping sinking to the file and then deleting it.

Here's one way you could implement that:

```
muffleMessages <- function(expr) {
    f <- tempfile()
    ff <- file(f, open="w")
    sink(ff, type="message")
    on.exit({sink(); unlink(f)})
    expr
}

muffleMessages(auto.arima(testseries))
# Series: testseries 
# ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 
# 
# Coefficients:
#       intercept
#        834.6000
# s.e.    42.4746
#  
# sigma^2 estimated as 9020:  log likelihood=-29.86
# AIC=63.73   AICc=69.73   BIC=62.94
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the OP wanted to capture the errors and warnings.

Comment: @eipi10 -- Could be. I thought the question was almost perfectly ambiguous about whether it was seeking a way to muffle or capture and examine the errors and warnings. Guess we'll find out when the OP chimes in.

Comment: withCallingHandlers might be able to help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433848/handling-errors-before-warnings-in-trycatch/19446931#19446931

Comment: Sorry, i noticed that my post was really ambigous, i clarified it now. While your solution isn't exactly what i was looking for, it'll probably be helpful for me at a later stage, so thank you for that!
Also sorry for the delay, posted the question before i went to sleep and now got back from uni.