# How to catch both error and warning of `file()` call?

Tags: r

calling `source()` for non-existing file generates both `error` and `warning`:

```
source('nofile.R')
# Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
#   cannot open the connection
# In addition: Warning message:
#   In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
#   cannot open file 'nofile.R': No such file or directory
```

I tried to catch the error in `tryCatch()`:

```
trysource <- function(src.file){
  result <- tryCatch(
    expr    = {source(src.file);},
    error   = function(e){cat('My error: ',   e$message, '\n');},
    finally = cat("finished.\n")
  ); 
}

trysource('nofile.R')
# My error:  cannot open the connection 
# finished.
# Warning message:
#   In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
#   cannot open file 'nofile.R': No such file or directory
```

as you see, it catches the error successfully. Then I added `warning=` part:

```
trysource <- function(src.file){
  result <- tryCatch(
    expr    = {source(src.file);},
    error   = function(e){cat('My error: ',   e$message, '\n');},
    warning = function(w){cat('My warning: ', w$message, '\n');},
    finally = cat("finished.\n")
  ); 
}

trysource('nofile.R')
# My warning:  cannot open file 'nofile.R': No such file or directory 
# finished.
```

Now it catches the warning but ignores the error! Can anyone explain why it happens and if there is any way to catch both?

Comment: Would it suffice to elevate warnings to errors and run the only-error-catching version? `options(warn=2)` By the way, if this means catch both simultaneously, I doubt you can do that. The warning may be queued and then the error caught; if you make the warning an error, it will be caught before the second error is generated. If seeing all is important, perhaps you could try wrapping your code in nested `tryCatch` blocks, where the inner catches errors and the outer warnings. I'm not sure exactly what you want though.

Comment: This question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433848/handling-errors-before-warnings-in-trycatch

Comment: When a condition is signaled, the proper handler (if defined) is called. The expression stops its execution. Apparently, `file` generates the warning first. So your `tryCatch` calls the `warning` function and then executes the `finally` part. The error is actually never generated. See `?tryCatch` for more details (not a soft read I should add).

Comment: Perhaps you need to process the warning event and then allow continuance.

Comment: thank you all for the comments! now I see there's no easy general solution. I checked the question mentioned by @MatthewPlourde where they suggest custom catch function (`MyLibrary.Sys.Try()`)... In my particular case, I mainly needed to check if the `source()` loading was successful or not, so maybe I should rather work on that specific question only.

Comment: use `withCallingHandlers(..., warning=function(...) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))` to handle the warning and invoke the continuation. As the first argument to `withCallingHandlers()`, use `tryCatch(..., error=function(...) {...})` to catch the error and terminate execution. Whatever expressions you're trying to handle are in the first argument to `tryCatch()`.

Comment: thanks @MartinMorgan, I will try to implement a solution with `withCallingHandlers`!