# How to write errors and warnings to a log file?

Tags: r

I have written an R function that downloads a list of files from an official statistics website. Some of the downloads fail and I would like to keep track of the error message.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11667111/2641825) suggest using `sink(logfilename, type="message")` to divert error messages to a text file but the [sink](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html) help page says:

> "Do not sink the messages stream unless you understand the source code implementing it and hence the pitfalls."

What are the pitfalls and is there an alternative to using sink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure of all of the pitfalls, I've read some people having trouble with `sink` not releasing file access to a log file, and you could potentially forget to reset `sink` to output back to console instead of the log file, which could potentially corrupt your log file. But you should be able to generate an error log by running your code to download the files through a try-catch block and writing out the error messages similar to below.

```
log.path <- # Path to log file

tryCatch({
  # Code to attempt
  log(q)

}, error = function(err.msg){
             # Add error message to the error log file
             write(toString(err.msg), log.path, append=TRUE)
          }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, `download.file` returns both an error and a warning. I have added `warning = function(warningcondition){
        # Add warning message to the log file
        write(toString(warningcondition), logfile, append=TRUE)` to the `tryCatch` block and now it writes the warning to the logfile, but it doesn't write the error any more. I have written a reproducible example with 2 functions in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/paul4forest/bfeb84d3d116f108d3cda3e497181a57). How can my function capture both error and warning to the log file?

Comment: A similar question was expressed here: [Handling errors before warnings in tryCatch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19433848/2641825)